# Intel Apollo Lake (J3455) random frequent freezes on UI and MCE error on boot

Tags: drivers, unity, intel, freeze

I'm having problems with *ASRock J3455-ITX* running *Ubuntu 16.10*.

First noticeable issue is related to random freezes in the system. They are definitely easier to reproduce while e.g. opening multiple tabs in Chrome, but they also can be sometimes encountered while simply having *Terminal* running `apt update` (while in Unity). Freezes can make whole system unresponsive (in most cases keyboard and mouse still works, but sometimes even they stop to respond).

While investigating this further, I noticed once in `dmesg`:

`mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged`

I installed `mcelog` and can see now the following in `/var/log/mcelog`:

```
mcelog: failed to prefill DIMM database from DMI data
mcelog: Family 6 Model 92 CPU: only decoding architectural errors
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 0 BANK 4
ADDR fef13b80
TIME 1484930342 Fri Jan 20 17:39:02 2017
MCG status:
MCi status:
Uncorrected error
MCi_ADDR register valid
Processor context corrupt
MCA: Internal unclassified error: 408
Running trigger `unknown-error-trigger'
STATUS a600000000020408 MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP c07 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 92
```

The interesting thing is that errors like this one are happening to me **on boot only** (but it repeats constantly on every boot) - but there are no signs of them while system is already running (even when I'm experiencing mentioned random freezes).

Does anyone of you how idea what's wrong? Is that error from `mcelog` a clear indication that I have some kind of a hardware problem? Or can it be a error caused by a mixture of kernel, drivers, firmware, microcode, whatever else?

Comment: Same problem here. I'm using ASRock j4205-ITX with Ubuntu Server 16.10 (w/o GUI). Memory HX318LS11IBK2/16. There is no trace in the dmesg or syslog. I've updated BIOS to 1.20 - no results. I've raised RAM voltage to 1.50 - still nothing. I was thinking of removing one of DIMMs, to see if it's memory related at all. ASRock says the motherboard supports up to 16GB but Ark Intel states it's only 8GB. I will post an update when I know something more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat as you with a ASRock J4205-ITX running Ubuntu 16.10.
mcelog output is identical with yours but I did not experience freezes while the system is running, possibly because I'm using it as a headless server.

However, there seems to be a random problem with the gpu when booting with a monitor attached. Ubuntu boots up fine and the system is accessible via ssh but the attached monitor does not display anything (no startup messsages and no shell login). I played around with grub parameters but it's still a hit & miss.

It might be kernel related or a hardware error. Unfortunately, this is all I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your BIOS to 1.20:

http://asrock.com/mb/Intel/J3455-ITX/?cat=Download&os=BIOS

Original 1.0 bios is very unstable.