# Asrock J4205 / Intel Apollo Lake will not install Ubuntu 16 / 17 (ASM1061 SATA optical DVD drive cd issue)

Tags: system-installation, 16.10

I have just purchased an AsR J4205 board, hoping to use it as a basic server / NAS - I had an older atom board doing this before, and although not an an expert systems admin am not a newbie either (used / installed Linux since ~ 1998), and have done some googling before posting, and read similar posts on here, Asrock and Debian forums.

So board is sold as Ubuntu 16.10 friendly, I've tried this and 16.04, 17.04 and the daily build, and the install always fails just after the grub screen, usually with

mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check : 0 Bank 4 a6000000000

sometimes also various other errors, eg : udevadm : relink 'libkmod.so.2 .....

I don't think this is just a UEFI issue, I've tried all options with the CSM mode, and both CD / DVD and USB installers

Similarly the board will install win 10, and boot (gentoo based)  current Sysrescue cd, so hardware is probably OK
I have updated the supplied bios (1.1 reported as buggy) to current 1.4

SO

- If anyone has this board working stably what did you do?
- I'm in single channel memory mode (checks ok with memtest) with one 8 gb Sodimm - would dual channel be any better?
- is board just too new / rare to be well supported?
- Could it be worth downgrading BIOS to 1.2 which is the version others have reported as working?
- any other ideas?

Can post further info, diagnostics if that might help.

Thanks

Comment: Try booting/installing Ubuntu with the `nomodeset` parameter set and see if you get further. If you do, I'll expand this into an answer that you can accept.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, seems to make no change. While I was there, tried taking out the quiet parameter, boot process is getting as far as seeing disks and some other system devices, last line refers to my install USB: sd:4:0:0:0 [sdc] attached SCSI removable disk

Comment: Tell me more about this "install USB: sd:4:0:0:0 [sdc] attached SCSI removable disk". Is this your target disk for the install? Is it USB or SCSI? If it's USB, is it USB2 or 3? What size disk? External enclosure... does it have its own power brick?

Comment: Thanks again @heynnema  
Sorry, that was a bit ambiguous. There are 2 HDDs, a 320Gb (sda) for the OS, and a 4Tb (sdb) to mount at /srv for files etc.  (Did try unplugging this to see if there was a 'big disk' issue)  
The sdc above was an 8 Gb usb stick with the ubuntu ISO written to it.
I've just tried again with a 17.04 cd, in case the USB was an issue, this time the last output before hanging is :  
`code`
[1.760233] sd 1:0:0:0:0 [scb] Attached SCSI disk 
`code` 
So I'm guessing it is the next step in the boot that is the problem?

Comment: Progress - The board has 2 sets of SATA sockets. 
One set is attached to the SOC, the other to a separate ASM1061 chip.  
I had the DVD rom drive on the latter, just moved it to the former and is now starting to boot.....
Don't really have time to play with it now, but will update further when I do!

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer, which might give others enough info to get their system working, or to give a fuller one if they have in depth knowledge of relevant hardware / linux boot process.

Worked out that next step in boot process might be initialisation of DVD drive, which I had connected to the ASM1061 sata socket (see note above)

Unfortunately the ASM1061 is allergic to (some?) optical drives - not sure if this is plain unsupported, bugs, incompatabilites or what.  Apparently some board / card blurbs warn about this in the small print. Mine didn't!
As above it didn't stop Win10 DVD booting, or sysrescue cd. BUT IT DOES CRASH BOOT OF UBUNTU SETUP, EVEN IF DRIVE IS JUST THERE, AND BOOT IS FROM A PERFECTLY OK USB STICK which is what foxed me for a while.

So easiest fix on this board is to swap sata cables about and connect DVD to SOC based controller, or not use it at all. There may be other options based on controller mode settings, or kernel parameters.

So now it boots and installs happily, just have to return my new hard drive because it has bad sectors and fails SMART :(  So can't comment on long term stability yet.

Further info in these threads:

[Can I prevent an IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE command to a specific device at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230396/can-i-prevent-an-identify-packet-device-command-to-a-specific-device-at-boot/232399)

[Boot failure: failed: command IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228927/boot-failure-failed-command-identify-packet-device)

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of this is faulty motherboard unit. I've had similar problems with system stability. All the upgrades of BIOS versions and newest kernel didn't help. I received new unit and it turned out to be motherboard issue. The new board was working perfectly fine.

Related posts
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1682999
[Intel Apollo Lake (J3455) random frequent freezes on UI and MCE error on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874234/intel-apollo-lake-j3455-random-frequent-freezes-on-ui-and-mce-error-on-boot)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with a very strange solution, worked for both Ubuntu 18.04 & Mint 19.2 : the quoted message appears more than once.

After the first time, I took the USB stick out, and then there was some sort of a message complaining about no media, so I stuck it back in. Then the installer started fine.

But I can't assure that it works till the end, since I installed it otherwise in the end: I installed the OS on another computer and transferred the medium to this one. Then I booted Ubuntu and started `bootrepair`.

After that, the issue was solved.